# R in shiny: How can I create a Slider with a range on which the value at the left end is higher?

Tags: r, slider, shiny

I am trying to create a Slider, which ranges from 1 to 0. So basically I want to reverse the scale. However, when I implement this as follows:

```
sliderInput("testID", "testLABEL", value = 0.5, min = 1, max = 0, step = 0.1),
```

a range from 0 to 2 instead of 1 to 0 is produced. I know that what I'm looking for is maybe quite uncommon, anyway, I would very much appreciate your help!

Comment: This won't help you at the moment, but the feature is being implemented for the next version of ion rangeslider (which shiny's sliderInput is based on), so you might see this option in the near future. See https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider/issues/234 There is also a Javascript solution on that page if you can make it work.

Comment: @warmoverflow: good to know.

[at]Patrick Balada: You could take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482731/shiny-sliderinput-from-max-to-min)

Comment: Thank you both for the helpful comments - I will have a look at the links and try to make it work!